# Submit HTML form type file with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form and a div. I want the user to select an text file and hit submit and that will populate the div with the content of the file. I would like to do that without having to refresh the page.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Click the "Choose File" button and browse for the file to import.<br /><br />
<input type="file" name="filelocation" value="Browse" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submitform" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="filecontent">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres is no easy way to do that, but u can use an Iframe with an ajax call to get your file to the server and work with it the normal ajax way

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" onsubmit="startUpload();" >
File: <input name="myfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

look at **target=**"yourhiddeniframe"

here is a complete howto:
http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

greetings

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to submit/upload the files via ajax. However, you can go for the [jQuery Uploadify plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/) to the trick for you.

> Uploadify is a jQuery plugin that
>   integrates a fully-customizable
>   multiple file upload utility on your
>   website. It uses a mixture of
>   Javascript, ActionScript, and any
>   server-side language to dynamically
>   create an instance over any DOM
>   element on a page.

Comment: Hmm can't you submit the form via ajax to a php file?

Comment: @Dalton Conley: Sure you can but the problem comes up when you try to upload a file via ajax :) You have to resort to iframes/ flash or some other solution to upload files via ajax.